# Send input to a program and get control back

Tags: c, shell, pipe, cat

I have been stuck on this for some time.
Let's say I have a C program like the following. I want to be able to send this program some string and get the control after that.
If I do:

--> cat myfile | myprogram

 or

 --> echo "0123" | myprogram

 or

 --> myprogram < myfile

 I get the ouput (myfile contains "0123")

 30 31 32 33

Using the -n option raises a segfault

 --> echo -n mystring | ./test

 zsh: done                echo -n "0123" | 

 zsh: segmentation fault  ./test

I also tried with a named pipe, but it didn't work either.

I would like to be able to do something like
cat myfile | myprogram
and get back the control so that I can type other characters.

```
  1 #include  <stdlib.h>
  2 #include  <stdio.h>
  3 
  4 int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  6   int i = 0, j;
  7   unsigned char buf[512];
  8   unsigned char x;
  9 
 10   while ((x = getchar()) != '\n') {
 11     buf[i] = x;
 12     i++;
 13   }
 14 
 16   for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
 17     printf("%x ", buf[j]);
 18   }
 19   printf ( "\n" );
 20 
 21   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 22 }  // end of function main
```

EDIT:

Below is the wrapper I have come up with.
It does everything I want, except that the output of the child exec-ed file is not properly displayed.

Without the wrapper:

```
$ bc
bc 1.06.95
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2004, 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'. 
2+2
4
```

With the wrapper:

```
$ ./wrapper bc
2+2
enter
4
```

Deleting the line

```
dup2(pipefd[0], 0);  // Set the read end of the pipe as stdin.
```

makes the child stdout display correctly, but of course breaks the wrapper.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

  int cpid;
  int pipefd[2];


  if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) { perror("pipe.\n"); exit(errno); }


  cpid = fork();
  if (cpid == -1) { perror("fork."); exit(errno); }


  if (cpid) {
    // Parent --------------------------------------------------------

    int buf_size = 8192;
    char buf[buf_size];
    size_t file;

    // Close the unused read end of the pipe.
    close(pipefd[0]);

    // Leave a bit of time to the child to display its initial input.
    sleep(2);

    while (1) {
      gets(buf);

      if (strcmp("enter", buf) == 0) {
        write(pipefd[1], "\n", 1);

      } else if (-1 != (file = open(buf, O_RDONLY))) {
        // Dump the output of the file to the child's stdin.
        char c;
        while(read(file, &c, 1) != 0) {
          switch(c) {
            case '\n':
              printf("(skipped \\n)");
              break;
            default:
              printf("%c", c);
              write(pipefd[1], &c, 1);
          }; 
        }
        printf("\n");

      } else {
        // Dump input to the child's stdin, without trailing '\n'.
        for (int i = 0; (buf[i] != 0); i++) {
          write(pipefd[1], buf + i, 1);
        }
      }
    }

    // Wait for the child to exit.
    printf("Waiting for child to exit.\n");
    wait(NULL);

  } else {
    // Child ---------------------------------------------------------

    // Close the unused write end of the pipe.
    close(pipefd[1]);
    // Set the read end of the pipe as stdin.
    dup2(pipefd[0], 0);  // Set the read end of the pipe as stdin.

    char** program_arguments = (char**)(argv + 1);
    if (execvp(argv[1], program_arguments) < 0) {
      perror("execvp.\n");
      exit(errno);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The segfault from the echo -n approach is from the fact that your line 10 looks for a '\n' and will continue reading through RAM until it finds one.

Comment: what do you mean by "get the control after that"? do you mean that the program have to do its reading (and calculation if any and output) without you have to wait it to finish? (so that whatever you do later will be likely intermixed with output from myprogram) ... in that case you can fork (while the segfault is given by a bug in your program, as already explained)

Comment: Yes. But I don't want this behaviour.
When I say I want control back, I mean that I would like my program to stay on the while(getchar() != '\n')
If I give "mystring\n" as input it should continue and terminate, but if I just give "mystring", the program should still wait for my input and a '\n' character. (This is why I tried the -n option with echo.)

Comment: The different behavior here is due to bc. You can run bc with "-i" flag to force interactive mode. Then most probably you'll see same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think it is possible to achieve this using named pipes if you can not modify the behavior of the program. Since in essence named pipes are no different  then giving the output from standard input with redirection.

I also do not think it is possible if you use pipe or redirection properties of the shell, since always an EOF is sent to your program in this case and you can not ignore EOF since you can not modify the program.

A possible solution is to use a wrapper. The wrapper will first read the prepared input, send them to your program, after the prepared input finishes the wrapper switches to standard input. Actual program just keeps consuming input, it is not aware of the actual source of the data.

Only drawback is, you can not provide prepared input with pipes or redirection, you have to supply a filename. (I'm not sure a named pipe will work or not.) The reason is obvious, if you provide the prepared input to wrapper from standard input then the same problem exists for wrapper. By this way you are just delegating the problem to wrapper, which you can design any way you want.

A possible implementation in C (modified from a similar wrapper I've used, not tested extensively):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    char c;
    char **pargs ;

    char buf[20];
    int n;

    int pipe_fd[2];
    int pid;

    pargs = argv+2;
    if (pipe(pipe_fd) < 0) {
            perror("pipe failed");
            exit(errno);
    }
    if ((pid=fork()) < 0) {
            perror ("Fork failed");
            exit(errno);
    }
    if (! pid) {
            close(pipe_fd[1]);
            dup2(pipe_fd[0],0);
            close(pipe_fd[0]);
            if (execvp(argv[2],pargs) < 0) {
                    perror("Exec failed");
                    exit(errno);
            }
    } else {
            size_t filedesc = open(argv[1],O_RDONLY);
            while((n = read(filedesc, buf, 100)) > 0)
                    write (pipe_fd[1], buf, n);
            while((n = read(0, buf, 100)) > 0)
                    write (pipe_fd[1], buf, n);
    }
}
```

You can run your program with this wrapper as :

```
./wrapper input.txt myprog possible command line arguments
```

You can put your initial input into `input.txt`.

A simpler solution is to reopen the standard input. However if you simply try to open it as if you are opening a file, it does not work. You should open the terminal stream and copy it to standard input of your application. You can do it (again by using a wrapper) with something like:

```
size_t tty = open("/dev/tty",O_RDONLY);
dup2(tty,0);
```

Not to mention this second solution is for Linux and not portable.

Comment: I finally came back to this.
A wrapper nearly achieves what I want to do. See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

In this example I use `tail -f`, not your C program

```
 mkfifo /tmp/pipe   # Open Pipe
 tail -f /tmp/pipe &    #  Start your program and put it into the background
```

Now you also can send data to your program that runs in the background

```
 echo "foobar" > /tmp/pipe
```

I hope this helps?

Comment: edit: Thanks for your answer!


This works well with tail and -f (follow) option, but does not if you remove it.
So it does not work for myprogram either.

I suspect tail -f won't stop after receiving the EOF or end of string character or something similar; but myprogram will.

Comment: Actually, I don't think your program will terminate on end of string (except by segfaulting) since getchar only tests against EOF (and is not even guaranteed to succeed at that) and the program only tests against newline.

Comment: Starting the program taking input from a named pipe and using a wrapper to write the pipe works quite well.
The only issue is that the input (in the wrapper) and the output are separated. It would be good to be able to interleave them, as if I was directly interacting with the program.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your program to accept 1 null character then continue on...it might work:

replace line 10 with something like

```
while (TRUE)
{
    x = getchar();
    if (x == '\n')
        break;
    if (x == '\0')
    {
        if (seen)
            break;
        seen = TRUE;
    }
...
```

Comment: If you can't edit the program you're using, then you're SOL. I recommend you use tail.